# Imprimir comandos ZPL

Tags: php, impresora, zpl

Estos trabajando con una impresora `X-printer XP-450B` para imprimir etiquetas adhesivas, para ello utilizo los comandos `ZPL`, en `PHP`.

Anteriormente había utilizado `EPL`, sin embargo el diseño con ese lenguaje es muy pobre ya que no permite modificar tipo de letra, entre otras cosas.

El código para imprimir los comandos es el siguiente:

```
require("ZplPrinter.php");

//Instanciamos de la clase ZplPrinter.php
$zepl = new ZplPrinter();

$texto2 = "123";
$texto3 = "43 - 10";
$texto4 = "#800";

$etiqueta = "^XA\n";
$etiqueta .= "^FO3,3^GB239,220,2^FS\n";
$etiqueta .= "^CFA,180\n";
$etiqueta .= "^FO5130,15^FD".$texto2."^FS\n";
$etiqueta .= "^CF0,20\n";
$etiqueta .= "^FO15,183^FD".$texto3."^FS\n";
$etiqueta .= "^FO175,183^FD".$texto4."^FS\n";
$etiqueta .= "^XZ\n";
//Función que imprime desde CMD
$zpl::send($zpl::compile($etiqueta, 1), $impresora, true, true);
```

La clase `ZplPrinter.php`

```
    class EplPrinter{
        
        public function __construct() {
        }
        
        public function send($label, $printer, $printD = true, $debug = false) {
                            
            // Crear archivo temporal
            $file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'lbl');
            
            // Abrir archivo para escritura
            $handle = fopen($file, "w");
            fwrite($handle, $label);
            fclose($handle); // Cerra el archivo        
    
            if ($printD) {
                // Imprimir archivo
                $print =  exec('print /d:"\\\%COMPUTERNAME%\\' . $printer . '" "' . $file . '"');
            }        
            
            // Eliminar archivo
            $delete =  unlink($file);
    
            if ($debug) {
                echo ("<h4>Comandos ZPL: ".$label."</h4>");
                echo ("<h4>Archivo temporal eliminado: ".$delete."</h4>");
    
                if ($printD) {
                    echo ("<h4>Impresión: ".$print."</h4>");
                }else{
                    echo ("<h4>Impresión: La impresión esta desactivada (habilitar en la función send).</h4>");
                }           
            }
         }

        public function compile($data, $quantity = 1){
           // Crear encabezado de la etiqueta
           $compiled = ''.(new ZplPrinter())->_eol();
        
           // Juntar los datos
           $compiled .= $data;

           // Añadir el final de la etiqueta
           $compiled .= ',' . (int) $quantity . (new EplPrinter())->_eol();
        
           return $compiled;
        }
         
        protected function _eol(){
           return PHP_EOL;
        }

}
```

El código funciona ya que al ejecutar la impresora imprime, pero en blanco.

Lo que busco es saber si algo estoy haciendo mal o si se requiere de algo más con este lenguaje `ZPL`, o si alguien conoce un método para hacer que `EPL` me permita modificar los tamaños y estilos de fuente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código ZPL es correcto, prueba a quitar los saltos de líneas:

```
$etiqueta = "^XA";
$etiqueta .= "^FO3,3^GB239,220,2^FS";
$etiqueta .= "^CFA,180";
$etiqueta .= "^FO5130,15^FD".$texto2."^FS";
$etiqueta .= "^CF0,20";
$etiqueta .= "^FO15,183^FD".$texto3."^FS";
$etiqueta .= "^FO175,183^FD".$texto4."^FS";
$etiqueta .= "^XZ";
```

Comment: Ya lo resolví, pero tú observación se aprecia. En realidad el problema era la computadora que de alguna manera no enviaba el paquete a la impresora.